# Wait till image is done loading to an array before appending the array to another array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array with data I get from Firebase like this:

```
profileImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
array.append(CustomModel(creatorID:creatorID, creatorPhoto: profileImage, creatorName: creatorName, documentID: documentID))
```

Now I need to append that array into another array like this

```
self.arrayOfArrays.append(array)
```

However when I append `array` it seems to leave it as empty, as (im guessing) the image is still loading onto `array`.

**My Question Is:** Can I use some sort of Dispatch or delayed that would wait till `array` is done loading before appending it to `arrayOfArrays`?

**PS:** I tried using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5)` and it works, but I need something that is not time based.

Also I cannot have the line just under the code:

```
array.append(CustomModel(creatorID:creatorID, creatorPhoto: profileImage, creatorName: creatorName, documentID: documentID))
```

because this will ruin the structure of the code.

Comment: Don't wait. Never wait. **Notify**. Add a completion handler

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use reactive approach using RxSwift & RxCocoa. You can achieve that this way:

Let assume that this is your struct as Codable:

```
struct CustomModel: Codable {
    let creatorID: String
    let creatorPhoto: Data
    let creatorName: String
    let documentID: String
}
```

Next create your firebase client that will create observable for fetching CustomModel from firebase database

```
class FirebaseClient {
    static var shared = FirebaseClient()
    lazy var firebaseRequestObservable = FirebaseRequestObservable()

    func getCustomModel() throws -> Observable<CustomModel> {        
        return requestObservable.getCustomModel()
    }
}
```

Next you must implement your observable with `getCustomModel` method that will return your `CustomModel` from firebase. I have set child name as `CustomModel`, but you can set it depending on your firebase structure. Also here you could return an array of data like `[CustomModel]`.Also we add `onNext`, `onError` and `onCompleted` methods that will return data or error or complete our subscription to observable.

```
public class FirebaseRequestObservable {    

    let citiesRef = db.collection("CustomModels")   

    public init() {
    }

    //MARK: function for URLSession takes
    public func getCustomModel<CustomModel: Decodable>() -> Observable<CustomModel> {            
            //MARK: creating our observable
            return Observable.create { observer in                
                Database.database().reference().child("CustomModel").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    guard let value = snapshot.value else { return }
                    do {
                            let customModel = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(CustomModel.self, from: value)
                            observer.onNext(customModel)                        
                    } catch let error {
                            observer.onError(error)                     
                    }
                    //MARK: observer onCompleted event
                    observer.onCompleted()
                })

                return Disposables.create {
                    task.cancel()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And finally in your `ViewController` call client `getCustomModel` method from client class that will return your data asynchronously.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customModel: CustomModel
    var array: [CustomModel] = []
    var arrayOfArrays: [[CustomModel]] = []
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let client = FirebaseClient.shared

        do{
            try client.getCustomModel().subscribe(
                onNext: { result in
                    //result is custom model from firebase
                    self.customModel = result
                    //append your data
                    self.array.append(self.customModel)
                    self.arrayOfArrays.append(array)
                },
                onError: { error in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                },
                onCompleted: {
                    print("Completed event.")
                }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
        catch{

        }
    }
}
```